# Setting button background with UIManager / ColorUIResource

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

Can anybody tell me, why in the following code setting a button's background fails when using a color retrieved from UIManager?
[This question is obviously too short to be accepted by Stackoverflow, but I have no more details to present.]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class BackgroundColor extends JFrame {
  public BackgroundColor() {
    setSize(400,300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 5));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JButton b= new JButton("Default");
    add(b);
    b= new JButton(""+Color.RED);
    b.setBackground(Color.RED);
    add(b);
    b= new JButton("Failed: "+new ColorUIResource(255, 0, 0)); // RED
    b.setBackground(new ColorUIResource(255, 0, 0));
    add(b);
    b= new JButton("Failed: "+UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.background"));
    b.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.background"));
    add(b);
    b= new JButton("Failed: "+UIManager.getColor("menu"));
    b.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("menu"));
    add(b);
    b= new JButton(""+new Color(238, 238, 238));
    b.setBackground(new Color(238, 238, 238));
    add(b);
    setVisible(true);
  }
 
 
  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(BackgroundColor::new);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could explain what you mean with “fails”, i.e. what did you expect, what did you get instead. Then, you don’t need a filler sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colors of type `ColorUIResource` have a special meaning: they are default colors, installed by LookAndFeel. And they may be interpret by a non-standard way.

Painting of button performes the current `LookAndFeel`. In your case: `MetalLookAndFeel`, or, more precise `MetalButtonUI`. Painting of button is defined in method `update` as following:

```
public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton)c;
    if ((c.getBackground() instanceof UIResource) &&
              button.isContentAreaFilled() && c.isEnabled()) {
        ButtonModel model = button.getModel();
        if (!MetalUtils.isToolBarButton(c)) {
            if (!model.isArmed() && !model.isPressed() &&
                    MetalUtils.drawGradient(
                    c, g, "Button.gradient", 0, 0, c.getWidth(),
                    c.getHeight(), true)) {
                paint(g, c);
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (model.isRollover() && MetalUtils.drawGradient(
                    c, g, "Button.gradient", 0, 0, c.getWidth(),
                    c.getHeight(), true)) {
            paint(g, c);
            return;
        }
    }
    super.update(g, c);
}
```

As you can see, if button has background of class ColorUIResource, this method provides painting of foreground only (probably due to performance reasons) by calling of method `paint`. And if you set a normal color as background, you avoid this behavior and call the line `super.update(g, c);` And here is the implementation of this method (defined in class `ComponentUI`):

```
public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    if (c.isOpaque()) {
        g.setColor(c.getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight());
    }
    paint(g, c);
}
```

Conclusion: do not use the class `ColorUIResource`, except you write your own LookAndFeel

Comment: Thank you, Sergiy, for your detailed answer. Doing a `System.out.println(b.getBackground())` after setting the background showed, that `UIManager.getColor("...")` in fact returns a `ColorUIResource`. So from that, one has to create a new Color and then it works.